# Tailwind issue with Size like w-80 w-96 or mt etc. how do solve?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3, tailwind-variants

i have the problem with tailwind that the w-96 show correct and w-86 show not correct, what is the problem ?

```
<body>
    <div class="mx-auto mt-20 mx-10">
      <div class="mx-auto justify-center w-98">
        <img class="" src="/image-product-mobile.jpg" alt="" srcset="" />
        <h1 class="font-bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. 
            Incidunt, accusamus.</h1>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Cupiditate praesentium eius deserunt aliquid cum saepe quod nemo provident magni modi.</p>
      </div>
  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[here the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXlwU.png)

Answer (score 0):

`w-86` is not a Tailwind class.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width

See the section on "Customizing your theme" and "Arbitrary values" on the above link.

Comment: ouuu thanks men hehe